# " Calculate the closeness criterion in Python "

Tags: python

I started Python and my plan is to calculate the closeness criterion according to the input file. The first few lines of the program read a text file that contains several numbers and convert it to an integer. I finally put this file in the Result variable and I want it to calculate the closeness criteria on these values but it gives the following error:

```
import networkx as nx   
with open('inputfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read(); 
    input_file = lines.split(' ')    
    Result= (int, input_file)
    c=nx.closeness_centrality(Result,0.2)
    print(c)
```

Error :

```
  File "inputfile.txt", line 6, in <module>
    c=nx.closeness_centrality(Result,2)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\algorithms\centrality\closeness.py", line 108, in closeness_centrality
    if G.is_directed():

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'is_directed'
```

Comment: You're passing a tuple `(int, input_file)` to `closeness_centrality` as the first argument. [Apparently](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.centrality.closeness_centrality.html?highlight=closeness_centrality#networkx.algorithms.bipartite.centrality.closeness_centrality) you are supposed to pass a networkx graph, not a tuple.

Comment: I want to do a closeness measure on the data file. What should I do?                                Please advise how to do this on the data file I have already prepared....

Comment: you need your data shaped in a way that can be parsed into a graph. Some options are adjacency lists or edge lists. Perhaps you are interested in https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/index.html but this question as it is is asking for something else. I suggest you edit it accordingly.

Comment: I do not want to put a number instead of the Result in this function c = nx.closeness_centrality (Result, 2). It's important for me to do this on my own data. what do I do?!